# How to replace complete word if I am selecting an option from autocomplete popup in ace editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Currently I am getting an option to replace prefix once I select from autocomplete popup in ace editor. If I want to replace complete word, How can I achieve this.

Comment: Please provide minimal code.

Comment: The word you would want to replace is enclosed in any bracket? Or is a pure string?

Comment: it will be a pure string